# The script is working in terminal but not work with js exec()

Tags: node.js, regex, exec

```sh
echo git@github.com:hasantezcan/journey-of-2021.git | sed -e "s/:/\//g" -e "s/ssh\/\/\///g" -e "s/git@/https:\/\//g"
```

this code is working on the terminal.

But if I try to run that script with javascript **exec()** it gives an error like that.

````````sh
Error: Command failed: echo git@github.com:hasantezcan/journey-of-2021.git | sed -e "s/:///g" -e "s/ssh/////g" -e "s/git@/https:///g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:439:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'echo git@github.com:hasantezcan/journey-of-2021.git | sed -e "s/:///g" -e "s/ssh/////g" -e "s/git@/https:///g"'
}
++++++stdout:    
```````stderr:   sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
````````

This is the code

````````js
await exec(
        `echo git@github.com:hasantezcan/journey-of-2021.git | sed -e "s/:/\//g" -e "s/ssh\/\/\///g" -e "s/git@/https:\/\//g"`,
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          console.log("linux test");
          console.log("------error:    ", error);
          console.log("++++++stdout:   ", stdout);
          console.log("```````stderr:  ", stderr);
        }
      );
````````

How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this fixed code:

````````js
await exec(
        String.raw`echo git@github.com:hasantezcan/journey-of-2021.git | sed -e "s/:/\//g" -e "s/ssh\/\/\///g" -e "s/git@/https:\/\//g"`,
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          console.log("linux test");
          console.log("------error:    ", error);
          console.log("++++++stdout:   ", stdout);
          console.log("```````stderr:  ", stderr);
        }
      );
````````

Comment: What is the **String.raw** @Ryszard Czech

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

Comment: @HasanTezcan I used it in order not to have to escape backslashes. *This is similar to the `r` prefix in Python, or the `@` prefix in C# for string literals.*